# How to fetch the datatype with column and create a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Mysql table have `student` have 2 tables `students` and `teach`

Code is below

```py
def tbl_col_names(table):
    db = {}
    for i in table:
        cursor.execute("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME= '%s'" % (i))
        tabledescription = cursor.fetchall()
        print ('tableDesc1', tabledescription)
        tableDescription1 = [i[0] for i in tabledescription]
        print (tableDescription1)
        db[i] = tableDescription1
        with open('data.json','w') as f:
            db1 = json.dumps(db)
            test = (f"data ='[{db1}]'")
            f.write(test)
    return db
cursor.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema='databasename'")
ecords = cursor.fetchall()
print (records)
member = [i[0] for i in records]
print ('member',member)
allcolumnvalues = tbl_col_names(member)
print ('all',allcolumnvalues )
```

data.json output is below

```
data = '[{"students": ["student_no"], "teach": ["last_name", "course_no"]}]'
```

How to fetch the data type along with column name

Below is the mysql query to get column name along with data type

```sql
select COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name='student';
```

```sql
cursor.execute("select COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME= '%s'" % (i))
```

My expected out `data.json` is below

```py
data = '[{"students": {"student_no":"int"}, "teach": {"last_name":"varchar", "course_no":"int"}}]'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cursor.execute('show columns from databasename.students')
records = cursor.fetchall()
d = {record[0]: record[1] for record in records}
# or d = {record['Field']: record['Type'] for record in records} if the cursor.execute returns a dictionary
```

This will return a detailed description of each field type including precision, such as `int(11)` or `varchar(32)`. If you do not want the precision included then:

```
d = {record[0]: record[1].split('(')[0] for record in records}
```

For each database/table you are interested in you would append the dictionary computed as in the above example as follows to a list to get your desired results:

```
def get_table_attributes(cursor, database, table):
    cursor.execute(f'show columns from {database}.{table}')
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    return {record[0]: record[1] for record in records}
    # return {record[0]: record[1].split('(')[0] for record in records}

data = []
data.append({'students': get_table_attributes(cursor, 'databasename', 'students')})
data.append({'teach': get_table_attributes(cursor, 'databasename', 'teach')})
```